# Can I change "Not Responding" message in title bar of window in dot Net C#?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

When application stop responding, **Not Responding** message appears along with application name. Like here:

[image: current result]

Is it possible to change this message in dot Net c#? I mean when application gets into not responding state system will show changed message instead of "Not Responding".

Expected result:

[image: expected result]

Comment: No, you can't. This is an operating system feature.

Comment: It's what windows does when the window is, you know, not responding. It can't *ask* the program what it would like to display there since that would require that the program be responsive. It would also be confusing for users who have *learnt* what "Not Responding" means.

Comment: That is not actually your window.  It is a replacement created by the OS, the "ghost" window, it displays a screenshot of the last known-good state of your window.  You could pinvoke DisableProcessWindowsGhosting() to prevent it from being used or (worse) edit the HungAppTimeout registry value, but neither are good ideas.  [Fix the real problem instead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/win7appqual/preventing-hangs-in-windows-applications).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't.

If you want to display a message while processing a long run task, you should consider creating a [Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx) (or similar) and let it do the heavy work.

That way you are not blocking the UI Thread and you can show your own message (e.g. in the [Titlebar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159419(v=vs.110).aspx)).